# If A is out then B is out. If C is out then D is in. What can I deduce?

Tags: logic

From: Philip Johnson-Laird [BA PhD Psychology (UCL)](https://dof.princeton.edu/about/clerk-faculty/emeritus/philip-nicholas-johnson-laird), Stuart Professor of Psychology Emeritus at Princeton.    (Author isn't  a logician.)    [*How We Reason*  (1st edn 2008)](https://www.amazon.ca/How-We-Reason-Philip-Johnson-Laird/dp/0199551332). p. 45.

> For premises that have several models, a single model consistent with
>   them—an example—establishes a conclusion about what is possible; but
>   all the models must be examples to establish a conclusion about what is
>   necessary. The opposite is the case for refutations: a single counterexample
>   refutes a conclusion about what is necessary, whereas all models must be
>   counterexamples to refute a conclusion about what is possible. And so we
>   should draw a conclusion about what’s possible faster than a conclusion about
>   what’s necessary, but we should draw a conclusion about what’s not necessary
>   faster than a conclusion about what’s not possible. This prediction is crucial for
>   a theory that takes possibilities as fundamental, and several experiments have

p. 45

> corroborated it. One caveat, learned the hard way, is that it’s no use asking
>   adults whether something is possible if it's [Author's bungle. This ought be "its".] necessity is obvious. They baulk
>   at saying, “yes”, in these circumstances; and so inferences have to be hard
>   enough that when an event is possible its necessity isn’t obvious too. Here is
>   a typical trial from an experiment. The premises are about a game of one-on-one basketball in which two players take part:
>
> > [1.] If Allan is in [the game] then Betsy is in.
> >     [2.] If Carla is in then David is out.
>
> The participants were more accurate and faster to infer that Betsy could be in
>   the game than to infer that she must be in the game. **If you list the possible
>   games compatible with the premises, you’ll discover that there are three games
>   and that Betsy is in all of them: Allan versus Betsy, Betsy versus Carla, Betsy
>   versus David.**
>     A way to create a problem to which the answer is, “no”, to both a question
>   about what’s possible and a question about what’s necessary is to change
>   “in” to “out” in the premises, and vice versa. The premises above are thereby
>   transformed into:
>
> > [3.] If Allan is out then Betsy is out.
> >     [4.] If Carla is out then David is in.
>
> The participants were now more accurate and faster to infer that Betsy need not
>   be in the game than to infer that Betsy cannot be in the game. The only possible
>   games are: Allan versus Carla, Allan versus David, and Carla versus David.

5. How can you efficiently deduce the emboldened sentence, without applying 3 and 4 to each person separately successively (1st: Alan v. B, C, D. 2nd: B v. C, D. 3rd: C v. D)?

I applied 3 and 4 successively, but didn't deduce the author's conclusions.

6. 3 says nothing about what happens if A is in. Thus why's  A v. B impossible?
7. The contrapositive of 3 is: A is in $\Longleftarrow$ B is in. Again,  why's  A v. B impossible?
8. How does 4 $\implies$ C v. D? Perhaps this is a typo? This book has many typos.

Comment: "How can you efficiently deduce the emboldened sentence, without applying 3 and 4 to each person separately successively "  What do you mean.  The embolden text is about 1 and 2; not 3 and 4 and you *do* deduce it by imply it for each player.

Comment: By 1.  Allen can only play Betty.  By 2. Charles and Daniel can't play each other and they can't play Allen by 1.  So they can only play Betty.  If anyone is playing it must be Betty or someone playing Betty.  So Betty is playing.

Comment: "3 says nothing about what happens if A is in. Thus why's A v. B impossible?"  Because 4 says if Carla is out (which she would be in a A v B game) then David is in (which he wouldn't be in a A v. B game.)

Comment: "The contrapositive of 3 is: A is in ⟸ B is in. Again, why's A v. B impossible?"  Because 4 says if Carla is out then David is in.  So either Carla or David is in.  And A v. B doesn't have either of them.  It's not 3 that is being violated.  It is 4.

Comment: "How does 4 ⟹ C v. D? Perhaps this is a typo?"  Where do it say 4 ⟹ C v. D???  4 implies C v. D is possible.  Not that it must happen.  4 ⟹ A v. B is impossible.  And 3 ⟹ B v C and B v D is impossible.  Together they imply B is out.